# "Hibernation device not found", although I have updated /etc/fstab

Tags: fstab, swap

I originally had a Linux swap partition on my computer, which I have removed. When I then tried to boot, I would get the error

```
ERROR: resmue: hibernation device 'UUID=f5eea.....andsoon' not found
```

which referred to the missing swap partition. So I commented out the line with the corresponding UUID (and which said "swap") in the /etc/fstab file (via a Live USB stick). Now my PC does in fact boot, but for a brief moment during bootup, I still get the same error message, along with the same UUID as before. I don't even know where else this UUID is stored on my computer anymore. What could be going on?

I'm on Manjaro Linux 5.8.18-1

Comment: Please add details about your Linux flavour. Which distribution and what version?

Comment: @Nils It's Manjaro Linux 5.8.18-1

Comment: Updated my answer with my findings for that one. Manjaro seems to be an Arch-fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device is most propably referenced in a kernel-parameter for your bootloader.

So you propably have to update either the bootloader-info or manually remove that reference from your boot-configuration.

This is where Linux distributions differ a lot. Ubuntu/Debian ist different. So are systems using grub (like SLES 11) or grub2 (like CentOS 7).

According to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182392) arch-linux article (Manjaro seems to be an Arch-fork) you should check:
*/etc/default/grub* and the setting of **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**

After correcting the settings you should run

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This is very similar to changing grub2-settings on other distros.

Comment: Check this `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`  If you have it and compare UUID.

Comment: @oldfred I don't have that directory. I forgot to mention I'm on Manjaro Linux 5.8.18-1, perhaps that's why.